# Matlab: how to make a 2D plot/animation from data in a single vector?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, vector, indexing, matlab-figure

I have a text file that contains calculation results from a two-dimensional (2D) flow calculation.  I want to plot the results in Matlab.  I did this kind of thing often years ago, but have forgotten how and would be very grateful for any advice.

A snippet of a results file is below.  The **left-hand column is the time step** (I only show data from time steps 45 and 46 as an example; the file is too long to post all the data).  The right-hand column is the hard part for me.  The **right-hand column corresponds to all x–y points** (so a single column of 2D data).  I know the number of x values and the number of y values.

My problem is that I don't know how to divide up the right-hand column for (i) 2-D plotting of (ii) a single time step.

```
   45.0000    1.0000
   45.0000    0.9742
   45.0000    0.9542
   45.0000    0.9521
   45.0000    0.9480
   45.0000    0.9436
   45.0000    0.9388
   45.0000    0.9326
   46.0000    1.0000
   46.0000    0.9742
   46.0000    0.9542
   46.0000    0.9521
   46.0000    0.9480
   46.0000    0.9436
   46.0000    0.9388
   46.0000    0.9326
```

...

I first want to make 2D plots of the x and y data. Then I want to animate them (i.e., a plot for each time step; I can probably figure that part out). The most important part is the 2-D plots. If anyone would be kind enough to point me to an example of how to create a 2D plot with the right indexing from a vector of data, I would be very grateful.

Comment: So you have various text files each at different time steps.... and your goal is at each time step, you want to plot the data at each time step in an animated plot? For example, at time step 1, show the points... wait for a few moments, then at time step 2, show the points, etc.  I'm assuming each time step will be on the horizontal axis?  Would this essentially look like a scatter plot with bands of points at each time step?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, rayryeng.  Sorry, I wasn't clear.  I have one text file for each calculation.  Each text file contains all results.  I want to (1) make one x–y plot for each time step, then (2) put all the plots together in an animation.  The part I'm most stuck on is (1).  I'll edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: So given a directory, you have files and inside each file, there would essentially be a 2D matrix of points.  You want to perform a 2D plot for each text file... by animated, I'm assuming you mean to show each of these sets of points separately?... do you want to clear the figure and show these points or add them on top of the figure? Do you want a new window? Are the names of the files anything sensible... i.e... is there a particular order that you're supposed to plot them in? You need to add more information. I shouldn't have to keep asking more information like this

Comment: I'm happy to provide more information.  I'm aware that I may not have been clear or that I may need to clarify because we may have different backgrounds.  But you're asking for more information because you don't understand what I said.  You don't have to answer if you are not happy with my question.  I do not have a directory.  I have a single file like the example I posted.  I want to create a plot that shows the right-hand column data as several X-Y plots.  Each X-Y plot shows data from only one time step (i.e., "45" in the left-hand column).  I ultimately want to animate the plots.

Comment: The name of each X-Y plot could be anything, but the time step (i.e., "45") would be a good choice.  I would prefer for all the plots to be preserved while proceeding through the time steps, if I have understood your question correctly.  I would like new plots/windows for each X-Y plot.  I can deal with whatever setup, but my biggest problem is that I don't know how to write a plotting code to make the X-Y plots from the column on the left.  This is probably basic, but I'm not having any success.

Comment: Is the number of values in the second column constant per time step? Do you always plot the same X-Y points?

Comment: Have a look at `textscan`, e.g. `C = textscan(fid,'%f %f',8)`.

Comment: Matthias W. Yes, the number of values in both columns is constant for each time step.  The X-Y values do change for each time step.  Thanks very much for your textscan suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not absolutely sure, if I understood your question so I am making some assumptions.

As I understood, the first column gives the timestep and the second column your measured flow data. I *assume* that the flow data measured at the same timestep are measured at different positions and you want to plot your flow profile for each time step.

This can be done using the following code, i.e. one separate plot for each timestep:

```
%% separate plot for each timestep
fid = fopen('test.txt');

while ~feof(fid)
    C = textscan(fid,'%f %f',8);
    figure();
    timestep = C{1};
    plot(C{2});
    title(num2str(timestep(1)));
end
```

An animation with all flow profiles in one figure can be generated using the following code:

```
%% animation
fid = fopen('test.txt');

figure(); hold on; 
while ~feof(fid)
    C = textscan(fid,'%f %f',8);
    timestep = C{1};
    plot(C{2}, 'DisplayName', num2str(timestep(1)));

    pause(1);
end

hold off;
legend show;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, snalx.  Yes, your assumptions are correct.  One thing I need to do is make a plot for each timestep.  So in the example in my question, I'd need separate plots for "45" and "46."  Is there a way of making a separate plot when the values in the left-hand column change?  Or--if that isn't possible--of specifying a certain number of values that should be included in each plot?  There are always the same number of values to plot for each time step.  I hope I'm being clear here.  Thank you very much.

Comment: the upper code example should work with changing values in the left column, given that you have 8 measurement values for each timestep. Have you tested the code with your data?

Comment: Thank you very much, snalx.  I initially had a problem not related to your example, but it is fixed and now the plots work perfectly.  Really appreciate all your time.  I tried up-voting you, but received a message that my reputation is too low for it to be recorded.